# User ID is incorrect in sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

The users account id is "bethg", and her sharepoint profile reflects this. In sharepoint designer, however, when I search for her full name the id shows as "elizabethg" and the workflow bombs. Get-spuser does not pull "elizabethg" either so there is nothing to remove. Where is SP designer pulling this info?

Comment: I would bet the original name for the user was setup as "elizabethg" and later reset to "bethg". Like if you put in a List Name and later change it, the original list name stays the say, but displays differently to the user/developer. Is there anyway to use a UID instead of the account ID? The number with the UID should not change. I'm not sure on any of this, so just leaving it as a comment.

Comment: what SP version (2010/2013) and edition (std/ent) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by typing in domain\bethg in SP designer user lookup. After I hit enter and went back in to do a look up, hovering over her name showed the correct user ID. Workflows are finishing successfully.

the environment is SP server 2010.

Thanks for the help!